# After creating hierarchical post type, still not getting any way to set parent

Tags: custom-post-types

After creating a custom post type like below, I still dont get any option to set the parent of the post, am I missing something?

```
register_post_type(
  'projects',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Projects',
      'singular_name' => 'Project'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5
  )
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding 'page-attributes' to the supports flags: `'supports' => array(..., 'page-attributes')`.